# ORA-29283: invalid file operation: nonexistent file or path [29434] trying to restore database or read text files

Tags: oracle, impdp

I have just installed Oracle 21c on a Windows 11 Professional machine.  I am trying to restore a database with this command:
`impdp system/*****@//localhost:1521/orclpdb dumpfile=mydumpfile.dpdmp directory=expdp_dir`

When I execute the IMPDP command, I get these errors:
`ORA-39002: invalid operation ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file. ORA-29283: invalid file operation: nonexistent file or path [29434]`

Prior to executing the IMPDP command , I ran these Oracle commands:
`create directory EXPDP_DIR as 'f:\backups'; grant read,write on directory expdp_dir to system; grant datapump_exp_full_database to system; grant datapump_imp_full_database to system;`

Searching the internet, it looks to be a permissions problem on the OS level.  I granted the users that are used for the various Oracle services permission to the directory specified by "expdp_dir" (in this case f:\backups) and still the error persists.  I even went so far as to grant "Everyone" "Full Control" over this directory and still no go.

I would expect that granting these permissions would solve the issue.  But, nay, it did not.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is F:\BACKUPS? Is it on a **database server** (should be), or your own **PC** (shouldn't be, unless PC actually *is* a database server)?

Comment: It is a local drive.  This is just my development machine and is not a proper server.  And, just to be more explicit, the Oracle server is running on my development machine and the drive is local to my machine as well.

Comment: OK, then directory really is located on a database server. Is filename really `mydumpfile.dpdmp`? Is it not just `mydumpfile.dmp` (extension)?

Comment: Yes, the directory is physically on the database server.  I am using the dpdmp extension but that's only because that's what I backed it up as from the original server.  I've done that for years - just to keep it separate from the old "imp" and "exp" commands.

Answer (score 2):

I checked this comment. It is not necessary to transfer the dmp files to the drive where Oracle is installed, but it is enough to create a directory object in that drive and create the import log files in it.

Answer (score 1):

There is unfortunately a known issue with 21c on Windows where directories that are on drives other than where the software is installed can incorrectly report as "invalid".

Assuming your software is installed on (say) C: drive, then an easy way to confirm this is to copy the dump file to the C:, temporarily use CREATE DIRECTORY to point to this local drive and then try import from there.

Comment: So, in my case, I have it installed on the E: drive.  And, this worked!  How in the world are you aware of that known issue?  I had previously tried moving the backup directory to the C: drive and I was still having that issue.  I hadn't thought to put it on the same drive as the installation.